# Каким образом в списке List найти повторяющиеся значения?

Tags: c#, повторы, list, список

Метод `Distinct` не годится ибо он удаляет не уникальные значения, LINQ тоже не пригоден так как было требование его не использовать.

Comment: ну вообще-то Distinct - это тоже Linq

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Пройдите в цикле по всем элементам списка.
Для каждого элемента списка пройдитесь по остальным элементам списка, найдёте равный данному - удаляйте (можно сохранить индексы таких элементов и потом все разом удалить).

Прикольно будет добавить сюда многопоточность для многоядерных ЦП (которой в LINQ, вероятно, нет).

P.S. Требование не использовать LINQ оправданно.
Согласитесь, сделать как я написал - сложнее, а значит, полезнее для развития.
Плюс LINQ нет в .NET 3.0 и ниже

Comment: Вы ухитрились выдать квадратичное по скорости решение, намного медленнее, чем LINQ.

Comment: > многопоточность для многоядерных ЦП (которой в LINQ, вероятно, нет).

Позвольте [удивить](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_PLINQ) вас.

Comment: >Плюс LINQ нет в .NET 3.0 и ниже

А вот в C# 1.0 нет обобщений и анонимных методов. Что же теперь, их тоже не использовать? Мало ли чего нет в доисторических версиях языка, стандарты которых записаны еще древними египтянами на своих папирусах. Это же не означает, что надо оставаться в каменном веке

Comment: @Водяной Змей: Мой ответ правилен: http://ideone.com/wRdues

Если вы об использовании LINQ, то
 * в рамках production-кода требование не использовать LINQ чаще всего нелепо, и вызвано отсутствием подходящего профилирования
 * если же это учебная задача, мы тут не решаем учебные задачи

Comment: DreamChild, не на всех компах есть .NET 3.0. Плюс бывают компы, на которых по некоторым причинам нет инета, значит, надо дистрибутив с собой таскать. Кстати, для установки .NET 4.0 на WinXP ещё пришлось бы таскать дистрибутив Windows Imaging Component. Не пришлось бы для .NET 3.0.
Или предложить заказчику подключить инет и только тогда согласиться делать работу? Послал бы я такого программиста на месте заказчика.
Анонимных методов не использую. Сколько написал коммерческих проектов, ни разу даже не попробовал создать такой метод.

Comment: VladD, а кто решает учебные задачи? Я не решал.
Зачем мне давать код? Напишите код по моему готовому алгоритму и протестите.
Не кидайтесь необоснованными доводами, когда указываете на ошибки. Если бы Вы не пошли гадить мне в комменты, я бы написал про левомеколь?

Comment: @Водяной Змей ваша нелюбовь к тем или иным удобным и хорошо зарекомендовавшим себя средствам языка может иметь любые на то причины, однако это очень слабый повод для того, чтобы ими не пользоваться всем остальным. Их придумали не просто так люди, которые отнюдь не глупее на с вами, и они давным-давно показали свою эффективность, что бы вы о них не думали 

>Или предложить заказчику подключить инет и только тогда согласиться делать работу? Послал бы я такого программиста на месте заказчика

пожалуйста, не нужно за меня выдумывать мою реакцию. И вообще, не стоит так нервничать. Несолидно как-то

Comment: 1) Нет никакой нелюбви, хочу - использую LINQ, хочу - не использую.

2) Я у Вас не спрашивал совета, стоит мне нервничать или нет.

3) Солидно-несолидно - это на работе. А форумы - развлечение.

Comment: @Водяной Змей: Написал код по вашему описанию. Может быть, ошибся, проверяйте: http://pastebin.com/smc13SXw

Результаты:

> List size: 100000  
> Warming up  
> Measuring (with LINQ)  
> Ready (with LINQ), time = 1097 ms  
> Warming up  
> Measuring (without LINQ)  
> Ready (without LINQ), time = 104029 ms

---
И правда, ошибся. Вот исправленный алгоритм: http://pastebin.com/5giHd6w3
Результаты чуть лучше:

> List size: 100000  
> Warming up  
> Measuring (with LINQ)  
> Ready (with LINQ), time = 1109 ms  
> Warming up  
> Measuring (without LINQ)  
> Ready (without LINQ), time = 70672 ms

Comment: 1) Многопоточность где?
2) Я не писал, что нужно сохранить индексы элементов удаления в списке.

Comment: Ну, у меня из без многопоточности быстрее. А если я неправильно реализовал вашу идею, реализуйте правильно и выложите код. Я лично не вижу, как можно распараллелить поиск повторяющихся элементов, так что распараллелить ваш код я не смогу.

Comment: @Водяной Змей вы чего огрызаетесь-то? Я чем-то уязвил ваше самолюбие очевидными фактами? Поверьте, здесь никто не желает чему-то вас учить, советовать и как либо вторгаться в ваше личное пространство, особенно если это так задевает вашу столь ранимую психику. Поэтому я искренне не понимаю, к чему так драматизировать адекватные и по делу сказанные слова других участников. Я здесь говорю исключительно по теме вопроса и ответов к нему, и заниматься с вами перепалками  на тему "не учите меня жить" - это явно не то, для чего мы тут собрались

Answer (score 13):

Попробуйте всё же LINQ.

```
list.GroupBy(v => v).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key)
```

Требование не использовать LINQ игнорируйте, скажите, что разработчику виднее.

---

Самое быстрое решение (`O(n)`), было бы, наверное, пройтись по списку, записывая по пути элементы в `HashSet`.

Comment: @VladD, скажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать о LINQ'e? Интересуют учебники или статьи, в которых подробно все описывается.  

----  

Просто смотрю на ваши ответы и понимаю, что это очень полезная вещь в умелых руках.

Comment: @teanЫЧ почитайте в MSDN. Это всего лишь набор методов в функциональном стиле, не более

Comment: @teanЫЧ: Я, если честно, вдохновился лаконичными однострочниками на stackoverflow, и решил сам выучить. Наверняка в хороших книгах есть, но я просто решал попадающиеся задачи и запоминал увиденные у других трюки (наподобие `File.ReadLines()`).

Ещё источником вдохновения могут служить функциональные языки: LINQ «одолжено» оттуда.

Comment: Оставлю здесь, может кому пригодится:
[101 LINQ Samples in C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Я не использую LINQ потому что толком  не знаю как он работает, можно было бы конечно прочитать про него, но задание требует стандартных методов решения

Comment: @factura: Тогда используйте решение под чертой. Там вроде всё просто.

И обязательно выучите LINQ, без него никуда.

Comment: @Triatel: Если у вас существенно другое решение, опубликуйте его отдельным ответом. Вы ещё наверняка получите за него какие-то баллы.